# Cohomology after completion

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

I've been scouring google and asking friend about something I was certain must be absolutely the easiest thing to people who do homological algebra, and none seem to know the answer to this, so if it's something really easy, I apologize.

The setup is relatively simple, I have a profinite group, $G$, and a sequence of $G$-modules--that is to say $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ modules--

$$1\to X_0\to X_1\to X_2\to 1$$

Given a trivial $G$ module, $R$ which is injective as an abelian group, I'd like to analyze the Galois cohomology groups, $H^*(G, R\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} X_i)$ given knowledge of $H^*(G, X_i)$. If it helps at all, one can assume I'm talking about $R=\mathbb{R}$, as even that case would be of great use. As far as I can tell, with a trivial $G$ action, $R$ is a flat $G$ module, so the snake lemma still applies to the modified sequence. The main problem I have is finding any result which indicates how the new cohomology groups relate to the old ones.

Furthermore, if I have a $\mathbb{Q}[G]$ module, $V$--that is, a vector space with a continuous $G$ action--how can I compute $H^*(G, \mathbb{F}\widehat{\otimes}_{\mathbb{Q}}V)$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and the hat means I intend to *complete* my vector space $\mathbb{F}\otimes V$ with respect to some topology (my case is a norm topology if that helps at all). Is it just the same as $H^*(G,\mathbb{F}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}V)$--i.e. does completion affect anything? (I'm inclined to think not, as the $\mathbb{F}$ are endowed with a trivial $G$ action, but I'm not enough of an expert to be confident of that.) If so, is then $H^*(G, \mathbb{F}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}V)$ the same as $H^*(G, V)$ or a simple operation away from $H^*(G,V)$?

**Edit**:  The answer posted by user 43326 makes me realize that I must have gotten the wrong tensor, it should be over $\mathbb{Q}$ (or even $\mathbb{Z}$) and not, $\mathbb{Q}[G]$ since the latter trvializes the $G$ action, which should not happen.

Comment: With trivial G action, R can't be flat.

Comment: On the second paragraph, the completion of finitely generated modules is exact, but $F$ is not finitely generated over $R$ or $C$, so probably the completion messes things up.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{F}$ is free over $\mathbb{Q}$, the tensoring is exact, so we have $H^*(G,{\mathbb F} \otimes _{Q} V)\cong H^*(G,V)\otimes _{Q} {\mathbb F}$.  The completion can still mess things up, do we know, for example, if the topology is Hausdorff?

Comment: Yes, the space $V$ is metric.

Comment: OK, so the completion won't do something too weird.  Is V compact? Another important point: how do you topologize ${\mathbb F}\otimes _QV$?

Comment: $V$ is a normed vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, I'm extending the topology of $V$ to $\mathbb{F}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}V$.

Comment: Let's see if I got this right.  Forget $G$-action (or take $G=e$) for the time being.  Consider ${\mathbb Q,\mathbb R}$ and ${\mathbb R}/{\mathbb Q}$ (quotient as vector space, actually we should take the complement) with standard norm.  Then the complete tensor product $V\hat \otimes _{\mathbb Q}Q$ will be ${\mathbb R}$ if $V$ is one of the three spaces above?

Comment: I think you're mixing up the notation of $R$ with this $Q$ you've introduced, but assuming that you mean $V\hat{\otimes}_{\mathbb{Q}}R$ with $R=\mathbb{R}$, then the first two are $\mathbb{R}$ and the third is trivial because $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}=0$ as a vector space since the projection needs to be continuous and $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ in the usual norm topology--this is how things work, at least, if I'm not much mistaken.

Comment: I see. But the point is that the category of topological vector space is not abelian, and when we take (co)homology with coefficients in topological vector spaces, usually we do it in the underlying category of discrete vector spaces.  So I am not sure if we can consider $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q=0$.

Comment: Right, in which case it's really, *really* complicated. $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ is--as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space really weird.

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to let $G$ act trivially on ${\mathbb F}$, the module
${\mathbb F}\otimes _{Q[G]}V$ is isomorphic to 
${\mathbb F}\otimes _{\mathbb Q}{\mathbb Q}\otimes_{Q[G]}V$ where  $G$
acts trivially on ${\mathbb Q}$.  But ${\mathbb Q}\otimes_{Q[G]}V$ is just
the coinvariant $V/G$, on which $G$ acts no longer.  So you get
$$H^*(G,{\mathbb F} \otimes _{Q[G]} V)\cong H^*(G,{\mathbb F})\otimes _{\mathbb Q}V/G.$$

Added after the edition of the original post.

Since $R$ is flat over $Z$, $\otimes _ZR$ is exact in the category of abelian
groups.  The forgetful functor from the category of $Z[G]$-modules to abelian 
groups is exact, which means that taking the (co)homology of (co)chain complexes is same in two categories.  So we have
$$H^*(G,X\otimes _Z R)\cong H^*(G,X)\otimes _Z R.$$

Comment: I must have erred in making the tensor over $\mathbb{Q}[G]$ then, certainly the action is not trivial on $V$. I'll edit my original post accordingly, and thanks for pointing this out.